# Google apps Script web app deploy for many users

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I programmed a web app and now i need to deploy it for my organization. There are 500 potential users. What factors i need to consider before the deploy? There's an easy way to deploy it? there are limitations to consider? what risks there are? there are a model or can you give tips or experiences for the deployment?

Comment: There is the quota limit of 30 simultaneous executions.

Answer (score 2):

There are no definable risks or dangers, it all depends on what your application does.

When you choose who are the users authorized to access, you will inevitably have to select ***anyone*** within your organization, otherwise only you (or the account with which the script was created) will be able to access. While as for the execution mode, you will have to choose how ***you*** or the ***user who accesses*** the application. This is important because if the application accesses an external service, such as Google Analytics, it can do so as the user with whom the application was generated or as the user who is accessing the application. Based on that selection you will see the Analytics data of one or the other Account.

So it all depends on what your application does and how it is to be used.